# What's the difference between libjpeg.so.8 and libjpeg.so.62

Tags: jpeg, decode, image-compression, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

There are always jpeg decoder libraries pre-installed on Linux like:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.0.2
```

What is the difference between the `so` library? Does `libjpeg.so.62` build from `libjpeg-turbo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you run:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*jpeg*
```

you will see that most of the files are just symlinks to the one with the full version, so programs can link against the latest one by specifying an unversioned library in the knowledge that it will point to the latest version:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Oct 20  2016 libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.62.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 Oct 20  2016 libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 436224 Oct 20  2016 libjpeg.so.62.2.0
```

Secondly, unfortunately I don't have the same files as you else I would help further, but in general, you can find which package a given file comes from like this:

```
dpkg -S someFile
```

So, on my system, I can see that `libjpeg.a` for example, comes from package `libjpeg62-turbo-dev`

```
dpkg -S libjpeg.a
libjpeg62-turbo-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a
```

Comment: I think it's `yum whatprovides someFile`